# What is difference between |0 and ~~?

Tags: javascript

Imagine two rounding function

```
function round1 (number) {
    return ~~number;
}
function round2 (number) {
    return number|0;
}
```

What is practical difference between them? I'm looking for in-depth explanation.

Comment: one uses two unary operations to cast a `Number` to a 32 bit integer, while the other uses a single operation and two operands to do the same.

Comment: zzzzBov's explanation gave me an idea... and they both fail for `n=Math.exp(33)` giving `-1705798981` in comparison with `Math.round(n)` or `Math.trunc(n)` `214643579785916` `214643579785915`

Comment: It's quite common knowledge - bitwise operators always converts operands to signed 32bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

Both operations are bitwise operations.

`~` is bitwise not (aka bitwise inversion)

`|` is bitwise or

the javascript spec states that any `Number` should be converted to an Int32 before a bitwise operation is performed (see: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.10)

Specific lines from the spec:

> 5) Let lnum be ToInt32(lval).
>
> 6) Let rnum be ToInt32(rval).

Answer (score 0):

```
~ is "not" (binary/bitwise)  ~3(011) => (100)4

| is  "or" (binary/bitwise) 0(000) | 3(011) => 3
```

~ (not) will toggle the bits where on it becomes off and where off it becomes on

|  (or) will give logical or between bits like `1 OR 0` gives `1`

**In your example** assure number is 3

here  `~~number` corresponds to `not(not(011))` => `not(100)` => `011 i.e 3`

here `number|0` corresponds to `011 or 000` => `011 ie 3`